# Retrofit - Expected begin Object

Tags: arrays, retrofit

Does anyone know how to read this file (array of array, i think??) with retrofit. Can't find any examples on the internet. Have tried
1. ArrayList
2. Collection
3. []
4. [][]
5. List

Error:
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3 path $[0]

File:
[[1518173474652,"0.10002000","0.10010300","0.10000100","0.10009300","51.46200000",1518173534651,"5.14685961",86,"27.11500000","2.71207304","0"],[1518173534652,"0.10009300","0.10025000","0.10009300","0.10010800","122.42800000",1518173594651,"12.25782098",123,"20.10800000","2.01471571","0"]]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're parsing it as a JSON, because of the error you received :

`Error: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3 path $[0]`

That file, unfortunately, is not a JSON file, it doesn't fulfill the JSON syntax requirement. To check this, copy-paste your file into any JSON formatter online and they can validate it for you.

You could try parsing it with a custom-made converter. [Example here](https://gist.github.com/fathonyfath/b6aa8f6f9e05d148a216).

Comment: I fixed it by using JsonArray. Then inspecting the elements of the JsonArray